# Extract REGEX definition from string

Tags: sql-server, regex, replace, split, regex-group

I'm trying to find out a way to extract the Regex  structure from  a given string.

Ex:

> People (school 850  Children), age 9

I know that `REGEX =  [0-9 (),]

Possibly  a Sql function  since I must query  Table with million of records

Comment: Um, what are you trying to achieve? I am having a really hard time understanding the question :/ What do you need from regex? Are there more strings, post a couple so that we can see how the differ.

Comment: Think if you have DB, and you  must group  strings with the same REGEX.  How is this possible?  I Expect something that can extract all the symbols and Characters has been used in each string.

Comment: `^.*$` will match all your records

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking. Use regex in `WHERE` clause ?